# Query entries from two sections, check date field for one section and include pagination

Tags: query

I'm having a page that shows entries from two sections: news and events.

The page has the following layout:

---

**All current event entries**

- Current event entry 1
- Current event entry 2

---

**All upcoming event entries**

- Upcoming event entry 1
- Upcoming event entry 2

---

**All news entries and all past event entries combined including pagination**

- News entry 1
- Past event entry 2
- Past event entry 3
- News entry 4
- News entry 5
- Past event entry 6

---

To query the current events i use the following query

```
{% set entries = craft.entries()
  .section('events')
  .startDate('<= ' ~ now|date('c'))
  .endDate('>= ' ~ now|date('c'))
  .orderBy('startDate asc')
  .all()
%}
```

To query the upcoming events i use the following query

```
{% set entries = craft.entries()
  .section('events')
  .startDate('> ' ~ now|date('c'))
  .orderBy('startDate asc')
  .all()
%}
```

I have no idea how to query all the news and past event entries.

The query should include:

- Query all entries from section news
- Query all events from section events where entry.endDate < now
- Sort all entries by post date
- Limit to 9 and include pagination

I came this far with the query:

```
{% paginate craft.entries()
  .section(['events','news'])
  .limit(9)
  .orderBy('postDate asc')
  as pageInfo, pageEntries
%}
```

What is missing: checking the event entries to see if the endDate < now.

I can't just add .endDate('< ' ~ now|date('c')) to the query. That would hide all the news entries, ofcourse.

I did search and read a lot of posts on stackexchange. Couldn't find a solution.

Anyone that could help me with this?

Comment: Would it be an option to use PHP for it?

Comment: I would rather stick to Twig. But, how would you solve this with PHP?

Comment: I would fetch the element ids with two separate queries and populate all elements in the end

Comment: Ah yes, ID's is the trick. Will post the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

First get entries from section events as ID's and check endDate < now:

```
{% set eventsIds = craft.entries()
  .section('events')
  .endDate('< ' ~ now|date('c'))
  .ids()
%}
```

Then get entries from section news as ID's:

```
{% set newsIds = craft.entries()
  .section('news')
  .ids()
%}
```

Then merge those two together:

```
{% set entryIds = eventsIds|merge(newsIds) %}
```

Then paginate by id, set orderBy postDate and limit to 9:

```
{% paginate craft.entries()
  .id(entryIds)
  .orderBy('postDate desc')
  .limit(9)
  as pageInfo, pageEntries
%}
```